# Displaying the recognition history in real-time in Dragon NaturallySpeaking

Tags: windows-7, dragon-naturally-speaking

In Dragon NaturallySpeaking we can display the recognition history as shown below. However, the recognition history window isn't updated in real time. Is there any way to display some recognition history window that would get updated in real-time?

[image]

I use Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12.5 Professional with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no way to display some recognition history window that would get updated in real-time in Dragon NaturallySpeaking.